# How to detect distance by signal strength using wifi?

Tags: location, wifi, signal-processing

I research about detect location without gps and i found i can detect location by signal strength wifi.
It can detect :

FSPL depends on two parameters: First is the frequency of radio signals；Second is the wireless transmission distance. The following formula can reflect the relationship between them.

```
FSPL (dB) = 20log10(d) + 20log10(f) + K
d = distance
f = frequency
K= constant that depends on the units used for d and f
```

If d is measured in kilometers, f in MHz, the formula is:

```
FSPL (dB) = 20log10(d)+ 20log10(f) + 32.44
```

From the Fade Margin equation, Free Space Path Loss can be computed with the following equation.

Free Space Path Loss=Tx Power-Tx Cable Loss+Tx Antenna Gain+Rx Antenna Gain - Rx Cable Loss - Rx Sensitivity - Fade Margin

With the above two Free Space Path Loss equations, we can find out the Distance in km.

```
Distance (km) = 10^((Free Space Path Loss – 20log10(f) + 32.44)/20
```

The Fresnel Zone is the area around the visual line-of-sight that radio waves spread out into after they leave the antenna. You want a clear line of sight to maintain strength, especially for 2.4GHz wireless systems. This is because 2.4GHz waves are absorbed by water, like the water found in trees. The rule of thumb is that 60% of Fresnel Zone must be clear of obstacles. Typically, 20% Fresnel Zone blockage introduces little signal loss to the link. Beyond 40% blockage the signal loss will become significant.

```
FSPLr=17.32*√(d/4f) d = distance [km] f = frequency [GHz] r = radius
```

how to demonstrate this method is true ?
Everyone can explain for me about it?

Comment: I think this belongs to [Physics SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to detect distance by signal strength using wifi?

Not at all. None of your assumptions about path loss apply in a typical scenario. WiFis don't happen in outer space; they almost always either happen in indoor scenarios or complex dense urban scenarios, where you have all of the following:

- strong multipath components in your receive signal,
- no reliable line of sight signal,
- fast fading,
- slow fading,
- interferer (this is an ISM band, after all),
- adaptive TX power,
- adaptive RX amplifiers,
- MIMO systems,
- nonlinear behaviour for certain signals (extreme PAPR mitigation by accepting clipping is often done)

Every single one of the above factors would make the free space propagation assumption with constant TX power wrong. But you have **8** of them.

Calculation of attenuation factors based on Fresnel zone occupation only makes sense for line-of-sight directed links, not for omnidirectional antennas* in deliberately multipathed channels.

- not accounting for digital beamforming in the MIMO case, but that won't make your problem easier...